# mount: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'

Tags: linux, vmware-esxi, raid1, sles

I have Suse Linux 12.1 and 
i am trying to mount a single RAID 1 disk, to explore the files in it. However when mounting it:

```
 # mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt/test
  mount: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'
```

I started reading  around and many advised to just force the filessystem type

```
  # mount -t ext4 /dev/sdc1 /mnt/test
  mount: /dev/sdc1 already mounted or /mnt/test busy
```

when trying

```
 umount /dev/sdc1                 
 umount: /dev/sdc1: not mounted
```

Could someone provide some advise?

I am running my machines insed an ESXI server and it is a virtual disk. However this should not play, as this disks are not used by any other machines

thaknks!

Comment: can you please post the output of fdisk -l ?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You should not mount it directly using `mount`. You need first to run mdadm to assemble the raid array. A command like this should do it:

```
$ mdadm --assemble --run /dev/md0 /dev/sdc1
```

If it refuses to run the array because it will be degraded, then you can use `--force` option. This is assuming you don't have `/dev/md0` device. Otherwise, you need to change this name.

When this command is executed successfully, you can mount the created device normally using:

```
$ mount /dev/md0 /mnt/test
```

Comment: In my case it does not work when I take 1 HDD only. Before is RAID 1 for 2 HDD

Comment: @tquang: Can you post the error message?

Comment: How do you 'remove' the created /dev/md* ?

Comment: @quimnuss: You can use `mdadm --stop /dev/mdx`

Comment: If anyone still gets the `mdadm: /dev/sdb1 is busy - skipping message` you can stop the device on with `mdadm --stop /dev/mdx` or check the `/proc/mdstat` to check if the device was automatically mount by your system.

Comment: # mdadm --assemble --run /dev/md3 /dev/sdb5
mdadm: /dev/md3 has been started with 1 drive.unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'.

Comment: mdadm: device /dev/sdd5 exists but is not an md array