# How to fix destroyed software RAID after Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, raid, software-raid, ubuntu-14.04

I upgraded a headless server from Ubuntu 12 to 14 following the built-in `do-release-upgrade` script. It seemed to run fine until I rebooted, and was left with an unusable machine. After the grub screen, all I get is a stream of messages that, after 30 minutes, haven't ended. The messages are streaming so quickly, I can't even see them well enough to google the errors.

How do I go about diagnosing this?

Also, how do I backup the hard drive? Using a LiveUSB, I'm able to see the hard drives, but I can't mount them because they're part of a software RAID. Running `mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt` gives me the error:

```
mount: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'
```

I read [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/383362/mount-unknown-filesystem-type-linux-raid-member) that I might have to rebuild the array with mdadm, but is that possible from a LiveUSB that shouldn't be able to write to the drives?

Answer (score 0):

I think your LiveUSB doesn't have MD drivers built-in, and that's why it doesn't recognize the RAID members.

You need to see if you can manually load the MD module on your LiveUSB, or then find another boot media which has MD drivers available. For example, [System Rescue CD](http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage) is one option.

Comment: Yes, following my link, I'm able to temporarily rebuild the array using mdadm in a LiveUSB, but I still don't know what caused the problem to begin with.