# Mount raid1 drive failed, drive is busy or partition not found

Tags: mount, mdadm, raid1

I have the same issue as this question a few years ago [mount: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'](https://serverfault.com/questions/383362/mount-unknown-filesystem-type-linux-raid-member). I want to mount a drive coming from a raid 1 array.
I followed the steps but `mdadm --assemble --run  --force /dev/md0 /dev/sda3`
return `mdadm: cannot open device /dev/sda3: No such file or directory`
When I try `mdadm --assemble --run  --force /dev/md0 /dev/sda3`
it returns `mdadm: /dev/sda is busy - skipping`

`fdisk -l` has following output

```
Disk /dev/sda: 3,64 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: MB4000GCWLV     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: ABF234AC-AA0E-4503-9D47-4CB545FE0074

Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048       4095       2048    1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2     4096    2101247    2097152    1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda3  2101248 7814035455 7811934208  3,6T Linux LVM
```

I don't really know why there is a microsoft partition, since I'm using a pure linux OS. The strange part is that `mdadm --examine /dev/sda` found a valid superblock for the drive sda but not for the partition sda3

```
/dev/sda:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.0
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 9397a1dd:3a50d858:797a0e7a:2da3d34e
           Name : any:0
  Creation Time : Thu Aug 13 16:04:09 2020
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 7814037128 sectors (3.64 TiB 4.00 TB)
     Array Size : 3907018432 KiB (3.64 TiB 4.00 TB)
  Used Dev Size : 7814036864 sectors (3.64 TiB 4.00 TB)
   Super Offset : 7814037152 sectors
   Unused Space : before=0 sectors, after=264 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : f0d22188:c82b36d7:f0d666db:cb911a6c

Internal Bitmap : -24 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Wed Oct 25 20:50:51 2023
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset -8 sectors
       Checksum : c39dfc43 - correct
         Events : 649938


   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```